# Double integral: why didn't the author substitute $y=4$ into $x=\sqrt{y}$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

[image]

As can be read in the second part of the question, the author defines $0\le y\le4$ and $0\le x\le\sqrt{y}$ when the region is interpreted as Type II.

Here is my question: we can see the lower bound for $x$ is $x=0$ and the upper bound is $x=2$, so why didn't the author substitute $y=4$ into $x=\sqrt{y}$?

Comment: Does it make sense why the lower bound for $y$ is $y=x^2$ (as opposed to $y=0$) when the region is viewed as Type I? Because it is the same type of reasoning.

Comment: @Adriano: Ah, I think I get it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, first of all: whenever you take an integral with respect to $x$ and $y$ and your limits are constants as in the integral
$$
\int_0^4 \int_0^4 x e^{y^2} dx\,dy
$$
Then your region of integration will be a rectangle (in this case, the square given by $[0,4]\times[0,4]$).

Compare this to the integral
$$
\int_0^4 \int_0^{\sqrt y} x e^{y^2} dx\,dy
$$
What this integral is ostensibly doing is the following: at each height $y$, take the integral along a horizontal line from $x=0$ until the curve $x = \sqrt{y}$. Take all of those integrals, and add them together to get your result, that is, 
$$
\int_0^4 \left[\int_0^{\sqrt y} x e^{y^2} dx\right]\,dy
$$
In other words, we would be taking the integral over the desired region.  Hopefully that clears things up.